# c# reflection parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, reflection

I have been trying to create an instance of the [SearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class of System.DirectoryServices.

According to MSDN, its implementation is this:

```
[DirectoryServicesPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
public class SearchResult
```

My reflection is like this:

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(SearchResult).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0];
SearchResult abc = (SearchResult)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
```

There is a value in `ctor` but upon invoking the constructor, an error occurs:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.
```

Why it does say that there's a parameter count mismatch when the implementation says it has no params in its constructor? I changed `new object[] { }` to `null` but it says the same error.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that DirectoryServices has no public constructor. Checking with Ildasm one can see that it has one internal constructor, but not a parameterless one.

Its signature is:

```
internal SearchResult(System.Net.NetworkCredential parentCredentials,
                         System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes parentAuthenticationType);
```

Because the class has a parameterized constructor, there is no automatically generated parameterless constructor available.

Comment: They do, there is no "Constructors" point in the navigation. Only Methods and Properties.

Comment: The msdn docs don't mention private or internal members, because they're not intended to be called by user code. They would mention it if there was a public parameterless construchtor. @CSharpie: There is, the constructors are named by their internal reserved name as ".ctor".